# Extend NSCoding to conform to URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am quite new to swift and would like to extend `NSCoding` to conform to the type URL. I need to define an input and output type and always get the error `Type 'URL' does not conform to protocol 'NSCoding'`.

```
//what it looks like before entering types
DiskCacheLevel<<#K: StringConvertible#>, NSCoding>()

//what I want it to look like (<InputType, OutputType>)
DiskCacheLevel<URL, URL>() //here the error occurs
```

How would I extend it to conform to the type `URL` as well?

Comment: The toll-free bridged Foundation class `NSURL` does conform to `NS(Secure)Coding`. Just bridge the `URL` type to `NSURL` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- You cannot “extend `NSCoding` to conform to the type URL” because you cannot extend a protocol to conform to anything, and `URL` is not a protocol that can be conformed to. Presumably you meant that you want to extend `URL` to conform to `NSCoding`.
- You cannot extend `URL` to conform to `NSCoding` because only classes can conform to `NSCoding`, but `URL` is a struct.

What you can do is use `NSURL` instead of `URL`. `NSURL` is a class, and you can freely convert between `NSURL` and `URL`. Since `NSURL` already conforms to `NSCoding`, you don't have to write an extension for that.

```
let cache = DiskCacheLevel<URL, NSURL>()

let key = URL(...)
let value = URL(...)
cache[key] = value as NSURL
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around in your code then? First URL and then NSURL: `<URL, NSURL>`?